# Java. layout cannot be resolved or is not a field

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Hi I am new to Android programming and working on Eclipse. I am having an error "layout cannot be resolved or is not a field" in the following program:

```
package com.esri.android.sample;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.esri.android.map.MapView;
import com.esri.android.map.ags.ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer;

import com.esri.android.R;

public class HelloWorldMapActivity extends Activity {
    MapView map = null;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // Retrieve the map and initial extent from XML layout
        map = (MapView)findViewById(R.id.map);
        // Add dynamic layer to MapView
        map.addLayer(new ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer("" +
            "http://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Street_Map/MapServer"));
        //Retrieve the non-configuration instance data that was previously returned.
        Object init = getLastNonConfigurationInstance();
        if (init != null) {
            map.restoreState((String) init);
        }
    }

    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        map.pause();
    }

    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        map.unpause();
    }
}
```

These errors are shown on the statements `setContentView(R.layout.main);` and `map = (MapView)findViewById(R.id.map);`

I do not know why it is showing these errors. Any idea what is the problem in this program?

Comment: Can we see your XML layout file?

Answer (score 1):

Try cleaning and rebuilding your project your R (Main resource) file is probably not working right.

Also check if you have a layout named main.xml and a MapView which has id map.
And also check if you are importing the correct R file.

```
 import com.esri.android.R;
```

This seems suspicious.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need not to use this line:

import com.esri.android.R;

bcoz u just need to add main.xml in res>layout
and R.java is automatically included in the generated java files folder.Therefore u do not need to import it using your package name.
Similar is the case for mapview.

does this work??

Comment: Hi,I am new to Android programming and working on a project in Eclipse.I tried the first tutorial'HelloWorld',and got this error:

Could not find class 'com.esri.android.map.MapView', referenced from method com.esri.arcgis.android.samples.helloworld.HelloWorldActivity.onCreate

I just read through this post and thought I might have a similar problem.Does there have to be a layout named'MapView'? If so,I do not have in my project.Could you please tell me how can I get it into the project?

I need help with this project and I need to complete it within a few days.I'd appreciate help asap.Thanks

Comment: Also, I am having the same problem in all my projects, although these are samples from ArcGIS, I'm just compiling them, still it shows these problems. I'd appreciate your help. I need to finish this but I'm stuck because of this problem.